# Lodash Map with mulitvariable function

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is it possible to use lodash to iterate over a collection and pass the item to a function that requires two (or more) arguments? In the following example, the function should take two values and add them. The map should take an array and add 10 to each. The following is how I thought this worked:

```
function x (a, b) {
    return a + b
}

var nums = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(_.map(nums,x(10)))
--->ans should be [11, 12, 13]
--->actually is [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

Comment: Partial application, `_.map(nums, x.bind(null, 10))`, or curry `x`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're essentially trying to do here is "curry" the `x` function, which lodash supports via [curry()](https://lodash.com/docs#curry).  A curried function is one that can take its arguments one at a time: if you don't provide a full set of arguments, it returns a function expecting the remaining arguments.

This is what currying looks like:

```
function x(a,b) {
    return a + b;
}
x = _.curry(x);  //returns a curried version of x

x(3,5); //returns 8, same as the un-curried version

add10 = x(10);
add10(3); //returns 13
```

So your original code is very close to the curried version:

```
console.log(_.map([1,2,3], _.curry(x)(10))); //Prints [11,12,13]
```

(As was pointed out in the comment on the question; `Function.prototype.bind` can also be used for currying, but if you're already using lodash, you might as well use something specific to the task)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];

function x(value, number) {
    return value + number;
}

console.log(_.map(numbers, function(value) { return  x(value, 10) }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, closure is awesome!  Just make a function that "closes" (wraps) your `x` function and passes 10 as its second argument.

```
function x (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function addTen (number) {
  return x(numberToAddTo, 10);
}

var nums = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(_.map(nums, addTen));
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're passing the argument for `generateAdder` into the inner function.

Comment: Yeah I originally wrote it so you could pass the number in, but removed that last minute for simplicity.  Missed that `10`.. thanks.

Comment: So then you might ask yourself, if you're not modifying the inner function at all, why do you need the outer function to generate it?

Comment: Bah... lol I scribbled it up quick.  Its late.   Im tired.  <insert excuses>.  Thanks :)

Comment: Honestly I'd just use `.bind`... but its better to start with this kinda thing when learning, and OP wouldn't have asked the question if he understood scope enough to use `.bind`